# java.lang.ClassCastException Why?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

I get this error as far as I understand it because of the type mismatch. After I receive objects from the database, I send them to another collection, and when implemented on a servlet, this error occurs ...

Does anyone have at least some assumptions why this error occurs?

```
[ERROR] 2019-06-25 23:09:30.807 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.chessman.work.database.entity.Resume] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.chessman.work.database.entity.Resume
    at com.chessman.work.objects.CollectionResume.<init>(CollectionResume.kt:8) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.chessman.work.database.service.ServiceResume.findAll(ServiceResume.kt:70) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.chessman.work.controller.resume.ControllerSearchResume.searchResume(ControllerSearchResume.kt:34) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
```

This function for search in database

```
fun findAllCustomQuery(maxWage: Double? = null, workType: String? = null, education: String? = null, experienceDays: Int? = null): List<Resume> {
        val separator = Separator()
        var sql = "SELECT r.* FROM resume r"
        if (maxWage != null) sql += " JOIN wage w ON r.wage_id = w.id"
        if (workType != null) sql += " JOIN work_type wt ON r.work_type_id = wt.id"
        if (education != null) sql += " JOIN education e ON r.education_id = e.id"
        if (maxWage != null) sql += separator.get() + " (w.count <= "+maxWage+" OR w.count IS NULL)"
        if (workType != null) sql += separator.get() + " wt.name LIKE '%"+workType+"%'"
        if (education != null) sql += separator.get() + " e.name LIKE '%"+education+"%'"
        if (experienceDays != null) sql += separator.get() + " r.experience >= "+ experienceDays
        val query = entityManager!!.createNativeQuery(sql)
        val list = query.getResultList() as ArrayList<Resume>
        return LinkedList<Resume>(list)
    }

fun findAll(): CollectionResume {

        val page = (if (request != null && request!!.getParameter("page") != null) request!!.getParameter("page").toInt() else CUSTOM_PAGE) as Int
        val size = (if (request != null && request!!.getParameter("size") != null) request!!.getParameter("size").toInt() else CUSTOM_SIZE) as Int
        val fieldSort = (if (request != null && request!!.getParameter("field_sort") != null) request!!.getParameter("field_sort").toString() else CUSTOM_SORT) as String
        val order = (if (request != null && request!!.getParameter("order") != null && request!!.getParameter("order")!!.equals("increase")) Sort.Direction.ASC else Sort.Direction.DESC) as Sort.Direction

        val pageable: Pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(order, fieldSort))

        val list: List<Resume> = findAllCustomQuery(60000.00,"полный день", "высшее", 365)
        return CollectionResume(list)
        //return CollectionResume(repoResume.findAll(pageable))
    }
```

This collection class:

```
class CollectionResume(): LinkedHashMap<Long, Resume>() {

    constructor(iterable: Iterable<Resume>): this() {
        for (r:Resume in iterable) { //ERROR
            super.put(r.id!!, r)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps specify the target class as the second argument to `createNativeQuery`:

```
val query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, Resume.class)
```

Without that each row is represented as an `Object[]`, so the return type of `getResultList` would be `List<Object[]>`.